# Selecting a column that is not an aggregate or in group

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The goal of this select is to get the latest score for a system that is in status = 'FD'. I want to get the ID of the row (id), the system ID (sys_id), and the score (score).

The following SQL gives me the id of the system (sys_id) as well as the score (score), but I also would like to get the id column associated with this score and sys_id. Hopefully that makes sense.

```
select sys_id, score from example
where (sys_id, end_date) in
(
  select sys_id,  max (end_date)
  from example
  where status = 'FD'
  group by sys_id
);
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle to give you an idea of what I am talking about http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/169a2/3

Before you ask, yes the combination of sys_id and end_date would give me a unique row and I could find the id that way, but I would rather get the id in my select statement.

Comment: Create a subquery that grabs the sys_id and max(end_date)...then join that subquery back to the original table to grab the values you need.  Hopefully you can work from there, to do full answer, I need some of your table info.  Don't use where in logic...inner join is much better

Comment: The table info is in the SQL fiddle link.

Comment: Heh, saw that eventually.   Answer is posted...same logic as Andrew really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple CTE to get the max date for each SYS_ID, and join that back to your table to get all the details for that particular record.

```
 with CTE as (
 select sys_id,  max (end_date) as MaxDate
  from example
  where status = 'FD'
  group by sys_id)

select
EXAMPLE.*

from
EXAMPLE
INNER JOIN CTE
  ON EXAMPLE.SYS_ID = CTE.SYS_ID
  and EXAMPLE.END_DATE = CTE.MaxDate
```

Check out the change to your [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/169a2/7)

Answer (score 0):

answer from comment.  SUbquery a is from your statement...lazy programming on my part.

```
select a.*, e.score
from
(
select sys_id,  max (end_date) as 'ed'
from example
 where status = 'FD'
group by sys_id
)a
inner join example e on a.ed = e.end_date and a.sys_id = e.sys_ID
```

Works on the predicate that there is only one unqiue value for a given sys_id and end date.  Multiple end dates will return multiple rows in a cross join format.

Comment: missed the from.   Should work now, sloppy on my part